# iOS: where does this initial view come from and how to delete it?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uiview, storyboard

In my build, I didn't select a Main Interface, and there's no view in my storyboard is "Is Initial View Controller".

Since I create one programmatically in app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()

    window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Everything works fine, the only problem is, whenever I open the app, the first view that show up is a view I didn't create.
In the middle of the view is the name of my app. The bottom is copyright(c) [the_company_name_I_put in.] 
And this happens before the above function is called.
Then the view fadeout and my first view appear.

I guess it's a view xCode build for me.
Is there anyway I could ask xCode don't create/show this view?

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift) tutorial from scratch without using their code. I couldn't find the difference between our code.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably haven't set your launch image, so the copyright appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8 allows you to use a Storyboard as the launch image and the templates included with Xcode 6 set up a simple storyboard with an *AppName* Copyright *yourname* message.

You select the use of a launch storyboard or launch images in the general settings section of your Xcode target.

[image: Launch image settings]

If you click "Use asset catalog" then you can specify images of various sizes for the launch image as you would have done in the past.

Note that the launch image is different to the initial view - The launch image is shown by iOS while your application is launching but before your code has started executing.  Once you app has finished launching it will be displaying the initial view (if you have specified one) or whatever view you set up in your app delegate.